# Is Snell's law a product of Gravitational Time Dilation?

Tags: refraction, time-dilation

Due to the proximity of atomic structures in a solid liquid or gas, does the gravity of these atoms warp time enough to cause light to move slower from the perspective of an outside observer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: gravity is irrelevant at atomic scales. Snell's Law is a consequence of the Huygens principle, which in turns is explained by Maxwell's equations. In the end, it is an electromagnetic phenomenon, and as such is explained by electrodynamics.

For more details, see the [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) article on Wikipedia.